# How to send table or View as embedded HTML <table> in an email

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, html-email

I have tried to send html table through java code

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
            try{
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            mailSession.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSubject("HTML  mail with images");
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                 new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));

            String html = "<html><head><title>" +
            message.getSubject() +
            "</title></head><body><h1>" +
            message.getSubject() +
            "</h1><p>This is a test of sending an HTML e-mail" +
            " through Java.</p>";

// HTMLDataSource is an inner class
            message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new HTMLDataSource(html)));

            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        static class HTMLDataSource implements DataSource {
            private String html;

            public HTMLDataSource(String htmlString) {
                html = htmlString;
            }

            // Return html string in an InputStream.
            // A new stream must be returned each time.
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                if (html == null) throw new IOException("Null HTML");
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
            }

            public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                throw new IOException("This DataHandler cannot write HTML");
            }

            public String getContentType() {
                return "text/html";
            }

            public String getName() {
                return "JAF text/html dataSource to send e-mail only";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have stored table data in ArrayList in the separate class.Below is the snippet of it.

```
List objList = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        conn=dao.DBConnection();

        sql1.append(" select MENU_ID, MENU_CODE, MENU_NAME, DESCRIPTON, ACTION_URL, CATEGORY, SORT_ORDER from m_menus order by MENU_ID ");


        iPreparedStatement1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1.toString());
        iResultSet1=iPreparedStatement1.executeQuery();

        while(iResultSet1.next())
        {
            afUserAdminMenuMaster objafuseradminmenumaster = new afUserAdminMenuMaster();
            Integer i=0;

            objafuseradminmenumaster.setMenuId(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
            objafuseradminmenumaster.setMenuCode(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
            objafuseradminmenumaster.setMenuName(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
            objafuseradminmenumaster.setMenuDesc(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
            objafuseradminmenumaster.setAction_URL(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
            objafuseradminmenumaster.setCategory(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
            objafuseradminmenumaster.setSortOrder(iResultSet1.getString(++i));


            objList.add(objafuseradminmenumaster);
        }
```

I want to embed that sql table in the mail body which will be dynamic depending on the condition.Please guide how should I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what part you're stuck on - creating an html table based on your data, creating a String that includes the html table data, or sending that string using JavaMail.  For the latter, your code is unnecessarily complex.  You can get rid of HtmldataSource and just use message.setText(html, "utf-8", "html").